# SharePoint 2007 Problem After Feb 2010 CU

Tags: sharepoint

We just applied the SharePoint 2007 Feb CU and there were no errors in the update process.  The problem is whenever we attempt to work with columns in a list (add or update) we get the following error:

Culture ID 1164 (0x048C) is not a supported culture. 
Parameter name: culture

This error happen on existing lists as well as newly created lists.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After a call to MS support, we managed to get this one resolved.  I don't know if this is something others will run into, but for some reason a VERY old version of the Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll was loaded into the GAC on the server.  This DLL should be located in the app_bin folder of each web application on the farm.  After we removed the DLL from the GAC everything started working.  We could not come up with a reason for why that DLL was in the GAC, but the server had been around since January of 2007.

Comment: These kinds of problems are why we are iffy to do any updates...

Comment: Nice, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had to shutdown the IIS service before I was able to overwrite the Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll file. One of the 7 .dll files was dated 2007 and all the others were dated 2011. Once I restarted the IIS service, the issue resolved itself.

Thanks again Ben and Jono.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a Feb CU for the different language packs you have installed or uninstall the language packs you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have any language packs installed on this farm.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's Answer helped us. We had a newer version of the dll in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\CONFIG\BIN\ and an older version in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80_app_bin.
I think there may have been a problem when I ran the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard after applying the Cumulitive updates.
I replaced the older version with the newer, restarted iis, and it resolved the error.

You also need to check the dll on every web app, as I found some updated and others didn't and once I added the new dll to every _app_bin it worked, thanks.